# Can I find the path to a DCOM application executable with WMI or Powershell?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, wmi, dcom

I have installed (and registered) a DCOM application on a [W2K8R2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) machine, and its GUID can be found in the DCOM list shown by dcomcnfg.

I can also use Powershell to find a [Win32_DCOMApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object for its GUID:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WMIObject Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting -Filter "AppID='{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA
}'"


__GENUS                   : 2
__CLASS                   : Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting
__SUPERCLASS              : Win32_COMSetting
__DYNASTY                 : CIM_Setting
__RELPATH                 : Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting.AppID="{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}"
__PROPERTY_COUNT          : 12
__DERIVATION              : {Win32_COMSetting, CIM_Setting}
__SERVER                  : MYSRV
__NAMESPACE               : root\cimv2
__PATH                    : \\MYSRV\root\cimv2:Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting.AppID="{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C269
                            60FA}"
AppID                     : {1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}
AuthenticationLevel       :
Caption                   :
CustomSurrogate           :
Description               :
EnableAtStorageActivation : False
LocalService              :
RemoteServerName          :
RunAsUser                 :
ServiceParameters         :
SettingID                 :
UseSurrogate              : False
```

The output shows that there is a DCOM application entry for my GUID. However it does not show the path to the executable. Is there a way to retrieve the application executable's full path with WMI?

Comment: What happens when you search the registry for `{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}`?

Comment: @JosephKern under HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}\LocalServer32 the registry contains the full path to the installed application executable

Comment: @JosephKern so I guess I only need to run a PS command which display this value

Comment: Yep probably. Or just `reg query` in cmd.exe, I added a an actual response as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Win32_ClassicCOMClassSetting class with Powershell

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_ClassicCOMClassSetting -Filter "AppID='{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}'" | select -ExpandProperty InProcServer32
```

or using WMIC

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path Win32_ClassicCOMClassSetting WHERE AppID^="{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}" Get InProcServer32
```

*this was tested on Windows 8.1 x64

or using reg.exe

```
reg QUERY HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}\Inprocserver32 /ve
```

Comment: This does not give any output in my Windows 2003 Server system - should it print out the value on the console?

Comment: I don't have a 2003 machine to test on. Perhaps you can use the reg.exe command.

Comment: The reg query one-liner does the trick, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you search the registry for `{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}`?

So the powershell component, this should get you started:

```
$cred = Get-Credential domain\user
Enter-PSSession <name of computer> -Credential $cred
Set-Location HKCR:\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{1CECFD4D-2CFB-4626-95C7-0266C26960FA}\LocalServer32
Get-ChildItem
```